# MySQLdb Module Python error

Tags: python

I have this method of an object that read all the table present in a database and returns the query's result.

```
def get_tables(self):
    self.__cursor.execute('SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema="{}";)'.format(self.__database))
    query_result = self.__cursor.fetchall()

    if not self.__cursor.rowcount:
        return False
    else:
        return query_result
```

The method is call from it:

```
query_result = get_tables()
for record in query_result:
    print record[0]
```

When i execute the script, i see in the console the result that i want and at the end this error:

```
Exception _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1") in <bound method Cursor.__del__ of <MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x7fbd06161910>> ignored
```

How can i resolve it?

Comment: There is an extra `)` in your SQL statement

Comment: As an aside, the `MySQLdb` module is old and all but deprecated – `mysqlclient` is a drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is broken:

```
... table_schema="{}";)
```

Remove the trailing `)`.